# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl

Tags: android, ios, admob, codenameone

My app is using the

> https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone cn1lib.

It is built and run OK with Simulator and Android but is failed to build with iOS. The error shows at server side is:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl error.

Does Shai/Chen/anyone has any advice with this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the actual error, you are seeing an error of the [screenshot process](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html).

To see the error scroll down and look at the bottom then look thru the file for the file mentioned in the bottom.

9 out of 10 errors of this type relate to missing or incorrect usage of the build hints required by a cn1lib.

Comment: It looks like the build is succeeded. Here is the information error log... 

    export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build8099143143814529397xxx/dist/build/Release-iphoneos/BeautifulPicturePuzzleFree.app


** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Comment: The full error log is here - https://thekingwilliamsolutions.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/cn1_ios_build_error.pdf

Comment: Your certificate/provisioning have a mismatch problem. Did you generate them using the certificate wizard?

Comment: I created them manually. I just re-generate them using certificate wizard and it works now. Thank you so much, Shai.